# Select an array with all the values of a particular field from an array of objects in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column that holds an array of objects:

```
[{"name": "Sue", "job": "dev"}, {"name": "Bob", "job": "designer"}]
```

I would like to select that column, but I am only interested in the values of the field 'job', so I would like an array like this:

```
["dev", "designer"]
```

I figured there would be a way to do this using the JSON operators and functions, but I couldn't find anything suitable here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html. Am I overlooking something in those docs? Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: a quick glance to the documentation you linked makes me think that the operand `->>` is what you're looking for; have you tried it?

Comment: It would help if you set up a dbfiddle.

Comment: @JoshPart I think the arrow operators can only select a single field. So select '[{"name":  "Sue"}, {"name": "Bob"}]'::json->> 0 will get me {"name":  "Sue"}, because that's the value in the first index of the json array. I can also use ->> 'name' to get a single name from a single object like {"name": "Sue"}, but something like '[{"name":  "Sue"},{ "name": "Bob"}]'::json->> 'name' doesn't get me all the name values in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_to_recordset and array_aggshould should solve your problem:

```
select array_agg(job) 
  from myTable
  cross join lateral 
  json_to_recordset(myTable.myJsonColumn) as t(name text, job text);
```

Here is an [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dcd50/1)

Note: Thanks to Tony for heads up about array. I missed it.